# htacces url rewriting with rewrite condition

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently, i have system which works through htaccess like need to hardcore url everytime a new product is added to the system, something like below

```
RewriteRule ^18th-and-19th-century$ sub_category.php?id=18th-and-19th-century
RewriteRule ^20th-century-furniture$ product.php?id=20th-century-furniture
RewriteRule ^pair-lacquer-cabints$ product_info.php?id=pair-lacquer-cabints
```

and also there are few static pages  as,

```
RewriteRule aboutus aboutus.php? 
RewriteRule contactus contactus.php?
```

the Idea here, what i want is to redirect the product info, category info to some index.php and access the static page as they are,

```
RewriteRule aboutus$ aboutus.php?
RewriteRule contactus contactus.php?
RewriteRule ^ index.php?
```

i tried this but everytime it takes me too the index.php page,i think there needs to some condition thing here but not able to understand how to go forward

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So, what did you try so far?

Comment: RewriteRule aboutus$ aboutus.php?
RewriteRule contactus contactus.php?
RewriteRule ^ index.php? @progsource

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub_category/([^/]*)$ /sub_category.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /product.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product_info/([^/]*)$ /product_info.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Output URLs will be

```
http://example.com/sub_category/18th-and-19th-century
http://example.com/product/20th-century-furniture
http://example.com/product_info/pair-lacquer-cabints
```

Comment: i acutally missed 2 more links, could you re check the question and answer. Thanks

Comment: Well, i'm not interested in adding a category or product keyword in the url.

Comment: @JacckieMer No issue but you have to add something unique in `URL` else how can `RewriteRule` identify your request is for `sub_category.php` or `product.php` or `product_info.php`

Answer (score 0):

You have wrote the all url at same directory level, so there is no way you can write dynamic .htaccess rule. You need to add some identifier or some pattern in all different kind of url's which are going to access different php page.

```
RewriteRule ^18th-and-19th-century$ sub_category.php?id=18th-and-19th-century
RewriteRule ^20th-century-furniture$ product.php?id=20th-century-furniture
RewriteRule ^pair-lacquer-cabints$ product_info.php?id=pair-lacquer-cabints
RewriteRule aboutus aboutus.php
```

Like in above pages you can use url's in following style

```
Subcategory URL: www.domain.com/18th-and-19th-century
Product URL: www.domain.com/18th-and-19th-century/list or www.domain.com/18th-and-19th-century/20th-century-furniture
Product info: www.domain.com/18th-and-19th-century/20th-century-furniture/pair-lacquer-cabints
```

OR

```
Subcategory URL: www.domain.com/category/18th-and-19th-century
Product URL: www.domain.com/product/20th-century-furniture
Product info: www.domain.com/product_info/pair-lacquer-cabints
```

So accordingly you can define levels and write rewrite rules.

Similarly you can write URL for static pages

```
www.domain.com/content/aboutus
www.domain.com/content/contactus
```

or
`www.domain.com/aboutus` [if you don't use first level URL for subcategory like www.domain.com/18th-and-19th-century then you can use for static pages]

if this answer is helpful to you then i will write .htaccess rules